# Practical open() file modes for writing

Tags: c, file-io, posix

In the `open()` C POSIX function, there are various flags for controlling the file mode such as for reading/writing, as well as specifying for cases where:

- You might want the file to exist
- You might want the file to not exist
- You might want to truncate the file if it does exist
- You might want to append to the end of the file if it does exist

For this, we are only interested in **writing mode (`O_WRONLY`)**. The interesting flags are `O_APPEND`, `O_CREAT`, `O_EXCL`, `O_TRUNC`, which are outlined here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/open.html

In my mind, the practical options you might want for writing only are:

- File must not exist, but will be created: `O_EXCL | O_CREAT` (Don't want to overwrite)
- File must exist, and will be appended to the end: `O_APPEND`
- File may or not exist, and will be appended to the end: `O_APPEND | O_CREAT` (Standard appending mode)
- File must exist, and will be truncated (it's possible): `O_TRUNC`
- File may or not exist, and will be truncated: `O_TRUNC | O_CREAT` (Standard overwrite)

**Are there any other practical/useful file modes for writing only? Is there a sensible case where you want to open an existing file and not seek to the end of the file to append?**

Comment: Of course there are use cases for not wanting to append. For example, you want to change (not add) something in the middle of the file (of the same size). There would be many other reasons.

Comment: An example would be a updating a game save file: No need to dump it all out again if the only thing that changed is that you traded 1500$ for +500 AK-47 ammo rounds. Instead just seek to the offset where money is stored and update that, then seek to the offset where ammo rounds are and update that too.

Comment: Ah, right. Cheers. So it would be a binary file with fixed offset data, and the open would be followed pretty much immediately by a seek.

Comment: @JetskiS-type For such a use case, also consider `pwrite()`. Notice that `pwrite()` is broken on Linux when opening files with `O_APPEND`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, of course, for that case you would need a data structure that can easily distinguish data that has changed since last savegame point (something that you have to put intentional thought and complexity into).

Comment: @JetskiS-type Oh, of course; But it would exist in memory only, and would serve as a quick checklist of things that need to be updated in the on-disk file; In effect, it's a cache!